# List customers with their purchases if they bought a particular item

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have the following tables:

**Table1**

```
ID  CustomerName       CustomerAddress
1   Joe Bloggs          123 The Street
2   Joe Bloggs Senior   345 The Close
3   Joe Bloggs Jnr      1 The Road
```

**Table2**

```
Table1_ID  Item
1          Toaster
1          Kettle
1          Microwave
3          Toaster
2          Iron
2          Kettle
2          Microwave
2          Slow Cooker
```

What I want, is a list of customers and the other products, they have purchased - if they have purchased a toaster.

I have used the following SQL query.

```
SELECT CustomerName, Item
FROM Table1
LEFT JOIN Table2
  ON TABLE1.ID = TABLE2.Table1_ID
```

which obviously gives me all the items bought by the respective customer.

If I try and put a `WHERE` clause in

```
SELECT CustomerName, Item
FROM Table1
LEFT JOIN Table2
  ON TABLE1.ID = TABLE2.Table1_ID
WHERE Item = 'Toaster'
```

I obviously don't get the other items.

I am totally stumped, how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This calls for a subquery, not a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT
  customerName
  , item
FROM Table1
JOIN Table2
  USING (id)
WHERE id IN
  (SELECT
     id
   FROM Table2
   WHERE item = 'Toaster')
  AND
  item != 'Toaster'
ORDER BY customerName, item
;
```

The subquery retrieves the **id** of people, who bought a toaster. The outer query accepts these **id**s and lists the people with their (different from toasters) **item**s.

See it in action: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/efb06/1).

### Extension

As asked for in a comment: To check not for a single but two particular items, you could work along:

```
SELECT
  customerName
  , item
FROM Table1
JOIN Table2
  USING (id)
WHERE id IN
  (SELECT
     id
   FROM Table2
   WHERE item in ('Toaster', 'Kettle')
   GROUP BY id
   HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT item) = 2
  )
  AND
  item NOT IN ('Toaster', 'Kettle')
ORDER BY customerName, item
;
```

The `GROUP BY ... HAVING COUNT` ensures, both of the indicated items were bought. `DISTINCT` is only necessary, when an individual (type of) item could be listed more than once for a particular customer.

See it in action: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/b81f11/1).

Please comment, if and as this requires adjustment / further detail.

Comment: how would i add another item to this list? so list of purchased items, if they purchased say toaster and kettle for example

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to list down all the products customer purchased; you need to use `GROUP_CONCAT()` like below. See [group_concat in SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html) for more information.

```
select t1.*, xxx.ItemList
from table1 t1 join
(
select table1id,group_concat(item) as ItemList
from table2
group by table1id ) xxx on t1.ID = xxx.table1id;
```